# Flurl Client Usage with Placeholder in URL

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, flurl

We are aware that it's important to make sure Flurl clients are re-used where possible and that this is controlled via the URL that is supplied to the `Get` method of `IFlurlClientFactory`.

Some of the calls we are making will contain a placeholder value such as:

[https://my.api.com/some/api/{0}](https://my.api.com/some/api/%7B0%7D)

Clearly we don't want to call `Get` using the full URLs like https://my.api.com/some/api/1234 or https://my.api.com/some/api/5678 since we would be creating new clients for each.

However what is the effect of calling `Get` using [https://my.api.com/some/api/{0}](https://my.api.com/some/api/%7B0%7D) compared to removing the placeholder and using https://my.api.com/some/api/?

Do these equate to the same thing as we would be calling `Get` with a key that isn't changing? We are just trying to validate that including {0} doesn't cause any change in behaviour.

**Edit:**

I realised I forgot to mention that we are using `PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory` as our implementation of `IFlurlClientFactory`

Answer (score 1):

The default caching behavior for Flurl utilizes the scheme, host, and port of the URL. It does not use the path. Therefore, all of these calls using the `HTTPS` scheme, `my.api.com` host, and port `443` will use the same client.

This is [mentioned in the docs](https://flurl.dev/docs/clients/):

> With the clientless pattern, all calls to the same host (or more accurately, same combination of scheme/host/port) will reuse the same client.

You can override the caching behavior if you need to, but it's probably unnecessary for the scenario you have described.

Comment: I realised I forgot to mention in my original post that we are using PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory. I think that might be different as it uses the whole URL?